# Bold greek letters using alphabeta and cfr-lm

Tags: fonts, greek, latin-modern, cfr-lm

I am using the `alphabeta` package in order to get upright greek letters in text mode.
I also want to use bold and sans serif upright greek letters in text mode.
This works well with `computer modern` and `latin modern` (using `lmodern`) fonts but not with others.
In particular I want to use the feature richer `latin modern` implementation from `cfr-lm`.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{alphabeta}    
% \usepackage{lmodern} % <- works just as computer modern
% \usepackage{cfr-lm} % <- different result compared to computer modern    
\begin{document}    
Ab\Gamma\delta123
\textbf{Ab\Gamma\delta123}
\textsf{Ab\Gamma\delta123}    
\end{document}
```

The `\textbf` and `\textsf` commands have no effect on the greek letters when using `cfr-lm`.
What is going wrong here?
Which part of the implementation difference between `lmodern` and `cfr-lm` breaks this feature?
How can I fix it?

Partial fix:
When I use

```
\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{clm2j}{cmr}
```

I can fix the bold letters, but is this the right way to go forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Greek font files (such as `lgrclm2j.fd`) for `cfr-lm`.  NFSS therefore tries to fall back to `cmr`, which happens to work for the serif fonts, albeit with a warning message, but fails for sans-serif (and would also fail for `\ttfamily`).

You could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{alphabeta}
% \usepackage{lmodern} % <- works just as computer modern
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % <- different result compared to computer modern    
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{LGR}{clm2j}{cmr}
\substitutefont{LGR}{clm2js}{cmss}

\begin{document}    
Ab\Gamma\delta123
\textbf{Ab\Gamma\delta123}
\textsf{Ab\Gamma\delta123}    
\end{document}
```

This tells NFSS to fall back to Computer Modern Roman and Computer Modern Sans Serif, which works.

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLateX, you could instead use the OpenType New Computer Modern, with

```
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
```